# How to select several aggregate values in one query in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to select min timestamp and max timestamp from a collection in one query.

All variants, like

```
 SELECT value min(c._ts), value max(c._ts) FROM c
 SELECT value min(c._ts), max(c._ts) FROM c
 SELECT values min(c._ts), max(c._ts) FROM c
```

produce errors like

```
: {"code":400,"body":"{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"Message: {\\\"errors\\\":[{\\\"severity\\\":\\\"Error\\\",\\\"location\\\":{\\\"start\\\":23,\\\"end\\\":24},\\\"code\\\":\\\"SC1001\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near ','.\\\"}]}\\r\\nActivityId: ad845eae-8b97-4f24-b372-dd5ce8f4d2a6, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.0.0.0\"}","activityId":"ad845eae-8b97-4f24-b372-dd5ce8f4d2a6"}
```

Is there such possibility in Azure Cosmos DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#ValueKeyword) about the value keyword, it doesn't look like you can have multiple value keywords in one query.

If you have a comma in the select statement then you're gonna get an error.

Sounds like a UDF or an SP is a more suitable solution for your problem.

Keep in mind that something like this `select max(c._ts), min(c._ts) from c` will throw the error: `Cross partition query only supports 'VALUE <AggreateFunc>' for aggregates`.

This indicates that if you specify the partition then you will be able to get it working but I just tried it with specifying the partition key and it still failed with the same error.